# Retrieve field value passed from Macro in Razor template

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am trying to pass a value from a macro into a razor template. But it doesn't seem to be working any suggestions?

Here is the macro code:

```
   <umbraco:Macro Alias="VideoInline" videoUrl ="[#videoUrl]" videoPosterImage="     <umbraco:Item field=' runat='server' Xslt='umbraco.library:GetMedia({0},false())/umbracoFile'></umbraco:Item>"
runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

Here's the razor template:

```
 @using System
 @using umbraco.MacroEngines



<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls 
 preload="auto" poster="@Model.getProperty(Parameter.videoPosterImage).Value" 
data-setup="{}">
 <source src="@Model.getProperty(Parameter.videoUrl).Value" type='video/mp4'>

 </video>
```

Comment: Could you post the macro code? Also did you add the parameters to the macro in the developer section? Btw, I think its `@Model.GetProperty(alias).Value` (capital "G").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing parameters into a macro, you should only need to access them with `@Parameter`. So in this case it would be `@Parameter.videoUrl`.

Also, don't forget that you will need to add the parameter to the macro definition in Umbraco itself in the *Developers > Macros* section.

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco 7 you have to use this code for getting parameters in Macro:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage
@Html.Raw(Model.MacroParameters["vidurl"])
```

Parameter class was removed